# else if statement in java returning syntax error

Tags: java, if-statement, syntax

Whenever I try to to an else statement, Eclipse highlights the line and says that the "else" is a syntax error and to delete it. My code looks like this

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class P4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
double grossSalary, interestIncome, capitalGains, totalIncome, adjustedIncome, totalTax, stateTax;
int exemptions;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Gross Salary: ");
grossSalary = input.nextDouble();

System.out.print("Number of Exemptions: ");
exemptions = input.nextInt();

System.out.print("Interest Income: ");
interestIncome = input.nextDouble();

System.out.print("Capital Gains: ");
capitalGains = input.nextDouble();

totalIncome = grossSalary + interestIncome + capitalGains;
adjustedIncome = totalIncome - (exemptions * 1800.0);

if ((adjustedIncome >= 0.0 && adjustedIncome < 10000.0));
        stateTax = adjustedIncome * .06;
        totalTax = 0.0 + stateTax;

        else if (adjustedIncome >= 10000.0 && adjustedIncome < 25000.0);
            stateTax = adjustedIncome * .06;
            totalTax = (adjustedIncome * .15) + stateTax;

            else if (adjustedIncome >= 25000.0 && adjustedIncome < 36000);
                stateTax = adjustedIncome * .06;
                totalTax = (adjustedIncome * .25) + stateTax;

                else (adjustedIncome >= 36000.0);
                    stateTax = adjustedIncome * .06;
                    totalTax = (adjustedIncome * .28) + stateTax;


System.out.printf("Total Income: $ %.2f", totalIncome);
System.out.println();
System.out.printf("Adjusted Income: $ %.2f", adjustedIncome);
System.out.println();
System.out.printf("Total Tax: $ %.2f", totalTax);
System.out.println();
System.out.printf("State Tax: $ %.2f", stateTax);
    }

}
```

The else if statements are coming back as errors as well. I don't understand what's wrong with the statements, because even when I try to put an else directly after the if, it still says that theres a syntax error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use condition with `else`:

```
...
else (condition) {
...
}
```

will give you compiler error. Another problem is that you put semicolons after each `if` or `else if` while you should be using curly brackets `{}`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the semi-colons and use braces

```
if ((adjustedIncome >= 0.0 && adjustedIncome < 10000.0)) {
        stateTax = adjustedIncome * .06;
        totalTax = 0.0 + stateTax;
}  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the semicolon:

if ((adjustedIncome >= 0.0 && adjustedIncome < 10000.0));

and use curly braces to properly define the scope of your if block.

if {
...
} else {
...
}

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're immediatly closing your `if` condition with a `;`, making the `else if` condition invalid.

What you want is:

```
if ((adjustedIncome >= 0.0 && adjustedIncome < 10000.0)){
    stateTax = adjustedIncome * .06;
    totalTax = 0.0 + stateTax;
}
else if (adjustedIncome >= 10000.0 && adjustedIncome < 25000.0){
    stateTax = adjustedIncome * .06;
    totalTax = (adjustedIncome * .15) + stateTax;
}
else if (adjustedIncome >= 25000.0 && adjustedIncome < 36000){
     stateTax = adjustedIncome * .06;
     totalTax = (adjustedIncome * .25) + stateTax;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. Don't place semicolons after the condition of an `if` or `else if` or `else` condition.  This semicolon will act as the block of the `if`, doing nothing, and the statements following it will always be executed.
2. Place braces around the section of code that is to be applied to the `if`, `else if`, or `else`.  Without them, even without the semicolon that was removed in (1) above, only the first statement will be taken as the block applied to the condition.

   if ((adjustedIncome >= 0.0 && adjustedIncome < 10000.0))
   {
       stateTax = adjustedIncome * .06;
       totalTax = 0.0 + stateTax;
   }
   else if (adjustedIncome >= 10000.0 && adjustedIncome < 25000.0)
   {
       // and so on

Also, there is no condition on the `else` block.

```
}
else
{
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use brackets to delimite the ambit of IF and IF ELSE

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class P4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        double grossSalary, interestIncome, capitalGains, totalIncome, adjustedIncome, totalTax, stateTax;
        int exemptions;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Gross Salary: ");
        grossSalary = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Number of Exemptions: ");
        exemptions = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Interest Income: ");
        interestIncome = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Capital Gains: ");
        capitalGains = input.nextDouble();

        totalIncome = grossSalary + interestIncome + capitalGains;
        adjustedIncome = totalIncome - (exemptions * 1800.0);

        if ((adjustedIncome >= 0.0 && adjustedIncome < 10000.0)) {
            stateTax = adjustedIncome * .06;
            totalTax = 0.0 + stateTax;
        } else if (adjustedIncome >= 10000.0 && adjustedIncome < 25000.0) {
            stateTax = adjustedIncome * .06;
            totalTax = (adjustedIncome * .15) + stateTax;
        } else if (adjustedIncome >= 25000.0 && adjustedIncome < 36000) {
            stateTax = adjustedIncome * .06;
            totalTax = (adjustedIncome * .25) + stateTax;
        } else if (adjustedIncome >= 36000.0) {
            stateTax = adjustedIncome * .06;
            totalTax = (adjustedIncome * .28) + stateTax;
        }
        System.out.printf("Total Income: $ %.2f", totalIncome);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.printf("Adjusted Income: $ %.2f", adjustedIncome);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.printf("Total Tax: $ %.2f", totalTax);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.printf("State Tax: $ %.2f", stateTax);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following an if statement, there are a few ways to execute the then code.

- Multiple code lines are wrapped in `{}`
- The first line of code is executed, which is terminated by `;`

In your code, by using `if ((adjustedIncome >= 0.0 && adjustedIncome < 10000.0));` the semicolon acts as the first line of executed code (even though there is nothing in between the `)` and `;`) and that is the end of the conditional statement.

Following that, there are two lines of code which execute without problem and then an `else` is discovered and it causes the error.

```
stateTax = adjustedIncome * .06;
totalTax = 0.0 + stateTax;

else if (adjustedIncome >= 10000.0 && adjustedIncome < 25000.0);
```

In order to use else, the `if` statement must have been followed by either `{}` or nothing.

- if(condition) 
  else {

  }
- if(condition){

  }else{

  }

Essentially you were looking for the latter here since you have multiple lines of code you want to execute which requires the use of `{}` for your if statement.

```
if ((adjustedIncome >= 0.0 && adjustedIncome < 10000.0)){
    stateTax = adjustedIncome * .06;
    totalTax = 0.0 + stateTax;
}else if (adjustedIncome >= 10000.0 && adjustedIncome < 25000.0){
    stateTax = adjustedIncome * .06;
    totalTax = (adjustedIncome * .15) + stateTax;
}else if (adjustedIncome >= 25000.0 && adjustedIncome < 36000){
    stateTax = adjustedIncome * .06;
    totalTax = (adjustedIncome * .25) + stateTax;
}else if (adjustedIncome >= 36000.0){
    stateTax = adjustedIncome * .06;
    totalTax = (adjustedIncome * .28) + stateTax;
}
```

Note that `else` works similar to `if()` so when nothing follows `else` the first code line is executed which is the `if(){}` code block. The else could also have looked like this

```
}else{
    if (adjustedIncome >= 36000.0){
        stateTax = adjustedIncome * .06;
        totalTax = (adjustedIncome * .28) + stateTax;
    }
}
```